# Why wouldn't Windows 7 have a "Repair your Computer" mode on F8?

Tags: windows-7, service-pack, windows-7-restore

I'm trying to follow the instructions [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975484).

> 1. Restart your computer and start pressing the F8 key on your keyboard.
>      You have to press F8 before the Windows logo appears. If the Windows
>      logo appears, you have to try again by waiting until the Windows logon
>      prompt appears and then shutting down and restarting your computer.
>      Note: On a computer that is configured to boot to multiple operating
>      systems, you can press the F8 key when the Boot Menu appears.
> 2. Use the
>      arrow keys to select Repair your Computer in the Advanced Boot Options
>      area, and then press Enter. If you are prompted, select the Windows 7
>      installation to be repaired, and then click Next.

But I don't have any "Repair your Computer" option or anything like it.  All I have is:

> Safe Mode
>
> Safe Mode with Networking
>
> Safe Mode with Command Prompt
>
> Enable Boot Logging
>
> Enable low resolution video (640x480)
>
> Last Known Good Configuration (advanced)
>
> Directory Services Restore Mode
>
> Debugging Mode
>
> Disable Automatic Restart on System Failure
>
> Disable Driver Signature Enforcement
>
> Start Windows Normally

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate (in the middle of installing SP1, but upon reboot my system is not bootable - keep getting C0000032 error in linked post).  I cannot boot into Safe Mode in any of its forms, and for whatever reason, in the past I have never been able to get my system to boot from a USB key (tried multiple bootable images, formatted them in FAT and FAT32, but always just get a black screen with a blinking cursor).

All I have is the Windows 7 Ultimate disc I used for installation, but when I boot to it and try to run the repair option, it says that it cannot repair the version of Windows that is installed (perhaps because SP1 is installed?).

Is there any other way that I can get to the repair mode on Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Boot from the Windows Installation CD ([download links](https://techdows.com/2011/07/download-windows-7-integrated-with-sp1-iso-official-direct-download-links.html)).  After selecting your language the next screen has a "repair" option at the very bottom of the screen.

Comment: "when I boot to it and try to run the repair option, it says that it cannot repair the version of Windows that is installed"

Comment: Download a copy of Windows 7 with SP1 built in.  

http://techdows.com/2011/07/download-windows-7-integrated-with-sp1-iso-official-direct-download-links.html

Comment: Nice, didn't know you could do that legally.  Good solution.  Unfortunately for me, my only other computer doesn't have a CD drive, so it will be a while before I can try it.

Comment: Figured out how to do it with my SP0 disc.  After selecting my language, I closed out of everything, and was presented with a list of recovery options.  One of which was Command Prompt, so I was able to open the command prompt, run the script I needed to run, and my system seems to be working now.

Comment: excellent.  You could have also used UNetbootin to make USB stick bootable and put the windows ISO on it at the same time.  I was going to suggest Command Prompt, but didn't know your level of technical knowledge.